# Can't get template to display using backbone.js and underscore

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm really new to Backbone, and I've looked everywhere to try and figure this out. Fundamentally I get how Models, Views, Collections and Templates work together, but for some reason I just can't get my Collection to render in a template. Using Firebug, I get a "this.model is undefined"

Here's my code:

```
(function($) {
window.Category = Backbone.Model.extend({});

window.Categories = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "src/api/index.php/categories?accounts_id=1",
    model: Category
});

window.categories = new Categories();
categories.fetch();

window.CategoriesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize:function () {
        _.bindAll(this,"render");
        this.model.bind("reset", this.render);
    },

    template:_.template($('#tpl-category').html()),

    render:function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

var testTargetvar = new CategoriesView({ el: $("#collection") });

})(jQuery) ;
```

This is the data that my REST service generates:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Web Design",
    "id": 0
  },
  {
    "name": "Web Development",
    "id": 0
  },
  {
    "name": "Waste Management Solutions",
    "id": 0
  }
]
```

The "fetch" that I'm using does show the fetched data in Firebug.

And lastly, here's my template:

```
<div id="collection"></div>
<!-- Templates -->
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-category">
<span><%=name%></span>
</script>
```

I've verified that all the necessary scripts, jquery, backbone, underscore, etc. are being loaded onto the page properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you're setting the `model` property of the view object.  Your view constructor also seems to be confused between whether it represents the collection of categories (as suggested by the `#collection` selector) or a single category (as suggested by the template and use of the `model` property).  Here is a working example that should help guide you to your complete solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/RAF9S/1/

```
( function ( $ ) {

  var Category = Backbone.Model.extend( {} );

  var Categories = Backbone.Collection.extend( {

    url : "src/api/index.php/categories?accounts_id=1",

    model : Category

  } );


  var categories = new Categories( [

    { name : "One" },

    { name : "Two" },

    { name : "Three" }

  ] );


  var CategoryView = Backbone.View.extend( {

    initialize : function () {

      _.bindAll( this,"render" );

      this.model.bind( "reset", this.render );

    },


    template : _.template( $( '#tpl-category' ).html() ),


    render : function ( eventName ) {

      this.$el.empty().append(

        $( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) ).html()

      );


      if ( ! this.el.parentNode ) {

        $( "#collection" ).append( this.el );

      }


      return this;

    }
    // render

  } );


  var view, views = {};

  categories.each( function ( category ) {

    view = new CategoryView( {

      tagName : 'span',

      model : category

    } );


    view.render();

    views[ category.id ] = view;

  } );

} )( jQuery );
```

In this case I've simply manually populated the collection with several models in lieu of your `fetch` method.  As you can see, I instantiate a view for each model and pass the model object as the `model` property.

In the `render` method I empty the view element (`this.el` / `this.$el`), then render the template and append the content of its root element to `this.$el`.  That's so I get the new content without wiping out the element itself.  Then, for the purposes of this example, I test whether the element is already in the document, and if not I append it to `#container`.

Comment: Hmmm, well, nothing happens. The error goes away but I get nothing displayed and no activity in the console. I replaced "whatever" with "Category" which is the initial model I'm creating.

Comment: I think that's because you're writing the code as if you already have an element in the document that represents each category you're creating a view for. I'll create an example that should help you find the way.

Comment: Thanks. I removed "window" and set everything to vars. I took the code you wrote and replaced my original "var testTargetvar = new CategoriesView..." with it. Still nothing. Sorry if I'm being a complete blockhead here.

Comment: @David, figuring out how to structure things can be confusing at first. You're not too far off. Take a look at the new example I posted and it should help you figure out how to link everything together to accomplish the goal.

Comment: It absolutely makes sense, extremely helpful, thank you. One more question, your example works for me, but as soon as I swap out the var categories with the sample data and change it to var categories = new Categories(); categories.fetch(); my page goes blank again. I've validated the JSON through a validator, so I'm still scratching my head. What am I doing wrong that the data isn't populating the view?

Comment: I'm not sure -- are you getting any JS errors? If not, I'd put a breakpoint on the line after the `fetch()` and see what `categories` consists of. If the models are there, then proceed to debug the rendering. If they're not there, then backtrack until you figure out why. You could try passing the `success` / `error` callbacks to `fetch()` in the `options` object. This probably goes without saying, but the model data does include a `name` attribute, right?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try those things. Definitely accepting your answer as it helped enormously. The problem must lie on my end somewhere, maybe in the REST service itself. I appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, hope it works out. Just step through it until you find what's really failing, so you don't end up on a wild goose chase. FYI, in case you saw my earlier example and didn't notice that I changed it...earlier I had the code passing `this.model.attributes` to the template renderer, then I looked at the documentation and I guess you're supposed to use `this.model.toJSON()`, like you originally had, so I changed it to that. I'm not sure it matters if you're only reading and not writing the attr values, but I guess `toJSON()` is what you're supposed to use in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I always load my templates in my functions...that might help..

```
initialize: function(){
  _.bindAll(this, 'render');
  this.template = _.template($('#frame-template').html());
  this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
},
render: function(){
  var $stages,
    collection = this.collection;
  this.template = _.template($('#frame-template').html());
```

Comment: then: `$(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));` like you do in your OP

Comment: Didn't seem to help. Added this and changed the template ID to mine. Page loads, no errors, but nothing displays and nothing in the console.

Comment: are there models with content? mine iterates through a collection and then spits out the models but only if theyre filled with info...https://github.com/raddrick/svgb/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/backbone/models/frame.js